# zsh: permission denied: reading anyway

Tags: laravel, macos, installation, macos-catalina

**this is the error its showing now**

[image]

I was installing **"Laravel"** through a tutorial and now i am facing this error **"zsh: locking failed for /users/vishnu.zsh_history: permission denied: reading anyway"**

macos:- catalina v10.15

I am using macbook air,
I don't have any idea what happened it happened while I was installing **composer** and a file was missing to get that file I ran some **"chown"** command and now I cant even open my chrome browser

**Please Help**

*-ThankYou*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run this command :

```
sudo chown -R ${LOGNAME}:staff $HOME
```

to make sure the owner is correct for your files.

Comment: Sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusernam /home/<yourusername>/.composer/composer.json

Comment: i have edited the question thats the error i am getting

Comment: Thsnks For The Helpp

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this also worked for me:

```
chmod 755 /Users/<mac username>/;
```